# Parse CLR Event with TraceProcessor

Tags: etw, .net-traceprocessing

I have followed the guidance at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/trace-processing/extensibility to get my hands on the .NET Runtime events. When I get a EventContext instance with the unparsed data I have no convenient way to parse things further?

Ideally there should be a parser generator for manifest based events like it is the case with TraceEvent. Something like

```
TraceProcessorGen -generateEvents c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CLR-ETW.man
```

would be a big help. I am not inclinded to manually write the parsing code with hundreds of hard coded offsets for dozens of events.

```
class ClrDataSource : IFilteredEventConsumer
{
    public IReadOnlyList<Guid> ProviderIds { get; } = new Guid[] { new Guid("e13c0d23-ccbc-4e12-931b-d9cc2eee27e4") };

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public void Process(EventContext eventContext)
    {
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> data = eventContext.Event.Data;
        // What do do next? 
    }
}
```

TraceEvent from Vance Morrison has an easy way to explore manifest based events where the Payload and PayloadNames are already preparsed based on their manifest. This is not very performant but for many cases and explorative research very helpful.

Comment: why don't you use TraceEvent?

Comment: @magicandre1981: I want to learn how to use TraceProcessor properly. I use TraceEvent with great results but its biggest drawback is that it always needs to convert an ETL file to an ETLX file. This is pretty time consuming. I was hoping to get something much faster which is (hopefully) TraceProcessor.

Comment: you don't to convert the ETL, direct parsing also works fine with TraceEvent

Comment: @magicandre1981: Yes I do that as well but the object model to get e.g. processes and related things need at some point in time an ETLX file. The API for e.g. Realtime ETW tracing is slightly different than the file based with different limitations and even more different when you rewrite an ETL. Tracelog is powerful but its API is pretty complex to use. TraceProcessor looks on the other hand very clean and fast which is the reason I want to give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I am a developer at Microsoft who works on the TraceProcessor project.)

IFilteredEventConsumer is a way to get at the unparsed events in the trace, and it's true that we have not added support for using a manifest file to simplify that parsing.

However, parsed events for that provider should be available in the [IGenericEventDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windows.eventtracing.events.igenericeventdatasource?view=trace-processor-dotnet-1.0) like this:

```
using (ITraceProcessor trace = TraceProcessor.Create(tracePath))
{
    Guid[] providerIds = new[] { Guid.Parse("e13c0d23-ccbc-4e12-931b-d9cc2eee27e4") };

    IPendingResult<IGenericEventDataSource> pendingEventsData = trace.UseGenericEvents(providerIds);

    trace.Process();

    IGenericEventDataSource eventData = pendingEventsData.Result;

    foreach (IGenericEvent genericEvent in eventData.Events)
    {
        // Process event here
    }
}
```

Within each [IGenericEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windows.eventtracing.events.igenericevent?view=trace-processor-dotnet-1.0), there is a property called [Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windows.eventtracing.events.igenericevent.fields?view=trace-processor-dotnet-1.0#Microsoft_Windows_EventTracing_Events_IGenericEvent_Fields), which should let you access events either by integer index or by name.

Comment: Thanks Maiak. That is much better than to manually scan through the fields. That makes TraceProcessor much more useful when parsing not predefined events.